# Universal Links on iOS with Ember.js

Tags: ios, ember.js, ios-universal-links

I have a simple `ember.js` app, and I would like to support [Universal Linking](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) to my native iOS app.  I have successfully done this with a simple apache server or node server, but I am new to `ember.js`.

How would I configure my `ember.js` app so that it serves a raw json file from the root directory of my site, like:

```
http://example.com/apple-app-site-association
```

The `Content-Type` of this file needs to be set to `application/json` as well.
Is there an easy way to do this in `ember.js`?

I tried just putting the file in my `dist` folder after building, but that didn't work.

Comment: Ember is frontend framework. this will not serve files/json response like webserver does.

Comment: Maybe its a question of configuring the server properly?  When I spin up the server using `ember serve`, it serves a `robots.txt` file from the `dist` folder.  Is it just hard-coded to do that, or can I set some config somewhere to serve more files?

Comment: `ember serve` is used only for development purpose not used for production.

Comment: That will work for my purposes - I'm really just experimenting so I can offer guidance on a real ember app maintained by someone else.

Comment: try placing your json file in `puplic` folder

Comment: Thanks.  That's almost it. Now I just need to set the content-type somehow. (I don't know why Apple couldn't have made this file have a file extension.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is so simple I'm tempted to just delete the question.

All `ember serve` does is serve the contents of the `dist` folder.
If you need a differently-configured server, just take the contents of the `dist` folder after running `ember build` and serve it from your own server.  Then you can configure it to serve the `apple-app-site-association` file as you need.